# Loop opening links with delaying time

Tags: javascript

I'm making a javascript in order to open several links in a quick way of some html page (not mine). My code is this:

```
var a,b,c,d;
a=document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
b=a.length;
console.log(b);

for (c = 1; c < b-1; c++)
{tempo();abrir();}

function tempo() {d=a[c].href;}
function abrir () {window.open(d, '_blank');}
```

The code works fine, except it opens all links at once and the server where the links are opened only opens the first, sending the other links to a homepage. So, what I need is to set some time between opening links.

I've read a bit now and tested a lot, including setTimeout() and the like.
I want it to work without any input, so i don't want alert pages and the like.

I'm running out of ideas...

Already tried:

```
for (c = 1; c < b-1; c++) {setTimeout(function(){tempo();abrir();},c*1000);}
```

And

```
for (c = 1; c < b-1; c++) {setInterval(function(){tempo();abrir();},c*1000);}
```

Didn't work...

Comment: What went wrong with setTimout?

Comment: It stoped, for the amount of time, and then opened all the others links at once.

Comment: You could try setInterval: `setInterval(function(){tempo();abrir(); }, 3000);`

Comment: I used:
    for (c = 1; c < b-1; c++)
    {setTimeout(function(){tempo();abrir();},1500);}

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 doesn't work either, makes it worse: for any 3000 ms it opens all the links, over and over and over ... (like the Moloko song!)

Comment: How about the below

Answer (score 1):

Well, due to for cycle in javascript, I have to make one by one like:

```
setTimeout(passarTempo1, tempoOff);
function passarTempo()
{tempo(1);abrir();}
setTimeout(passarTempo2, 2*tempoOff);
function passarTempo()
{tempo(1);abrir();}
// and so on...
```

If it would have a next c, like in other languages, this wouldn't happen...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This way each one will start one sec apart.

```
for (c = 1; c < b-1; c++) {setTimeout(function(){tempo();abrir();},c*1000);}
```

Comment: Strange, it opens b-2 (correct) blank pages... but at the right time...

Comment: Then maybe it should be `b+1` instead of `b-1`

Comment: its b-2. But only opens the last one. Meaning it runs all the c values in the for cycle and retains and runs the last value only...